# Counting NA grouped by factor

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to count the amount of NA's a column has per factor. I will use the `mtcars` data frame to make this more visual.

[image]

Looking at the data I would like to get something returned like:

```
mpg          count(NA_in_column_carb)
21.0         0
21.4         0
17.3         0
```

In SQL terms I would first like to group the data by `mpg` (mpg will be a factor in this case) and then count the amount of `NA` values that appear for each group in the `carb` column.

I tried writing something using dplyr but got stuck as it does not produce the correct result but rather produces an error.

The code:

```
mtcars %>% group_by(mpg, carb) %>% select(mpg, n = n(is.na(carb)))
```

The error:

```
Error in n(is.na(carb)) : unused argument (is.na(carb))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `sum` with `is.na` :

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% group_by(mpg) %>% summarise(n = sum(is.na(carb)))
```

The equivalent in base R

1. `aggregate`

   ```
   aggregate(carb~mpg, mtcars, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
   ```
2. `tapply`

   ```
   tapply(mtcars$carb, mtcars$mpg, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
   ```

and `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mtcars)[, .(sum = sum(is.na(carb))), mpg]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `rowsum` in `base R`

```
rowsum(+(is.na(mtcars$carb)), mtcars$mpg)
```